# unable to convert json array to json list

Tags: android

Graph api returning json array data here is it's detail [image: image contains the list of json array]

I had a Task to display these json array to my recyclerView so i tried  to convert json array  to a arraylist  but my array List Returning 0 . 
i am not getting what probable changes needed for the correct parsing here is my detail code

```
                GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/posts", null,HttpMethod.GET,
                GraphRequest.Callback { response ->
                    Log.e(TAG, response.toString())

                    try {


                        var json: JSONObject = response.jsonObject
                        var jarray: JSONArray = json.getJSONArray("data")

                            mArrayList = ArrayList()



                            for (i in 0 until jarray.length()) {

                               // mArrayList = ArrayList()
                                var mdataa: JSONObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i)

                                if (mdataa == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(this, " Nothing here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                                // this part don't have any mistake


                                mMessage = mdataa.getString("message")
                                mId = mdataa.getString("id")
                                mCreatedTime = mdataa.getString("created_time")
                                this.mArrayList?.add(Data(mMessage, mId, mCreatedTime))

                            }




                    } catch (e: JSONException) {

                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(this,"total number of values in arraylist" + mArrayList?.size ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() // this toast returning 0 value



                    if (mArrayList == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "U GET Nothing here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {


                        var main: Intent = Intent(this@Display, DisplayingPost::class.java)

                        main.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", mArrayList)
                        startActivity(main)


                    }
                }

        ).executeAsync()
```

updated: i tried this still it's returning null
            try {

```
                        var jsonResponse:JSONObject= JSONObject(response.toString())
                        var jsonArray:JSONArray=jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data")

                        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length())
                        {
                            var insidata:JSONObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            var mMessage:String=insidata.getString("message")
                            allMessage?.add(mMessage)
                            var mId:String=insidata.getString("id")
                            allId?.add(mId)
                            var dateofCreation:String=insidata.getString("created_time")
                            allCreatedDate?.add("dateofCreation")

                        }


                    }

                    catch (e: JSONException)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Size here is"+ allId?.size ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }

        ).executeAsync()
```

For Now I removed try catch block  and changed few line of code which resulted in a Toast message that was Displaying my JSONArray size which was 25 but when i tired to  fetch each object inside for block and displayed a Toast for value Outside of "for" block it is  Still Returning null  here is my new line of code .

```
                           //  try {


                        var jsonResponse:JSONObject=  response.getJSONObject()
                    // JSONObject(response.toString())
                        var jsonArray:JSONArray=jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data")
                  //  Toast.makeText(this,"Size here is"+ jsonArray.length() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length())
                        {
                            var insidata:JSONObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            if (insidata.has("message")) {
                                var mMessage: String? = insidata.getString("message")
                                allMessage?.add(mMessage as String)
                            }

                            var mId:String=insidata.getString("id")
                            allId?.add(mId)
                            var dateOfCreation:String=insidata.getString("created_time")
                            allCreatedDate?.add(dateOfCreation)

                        }


                  //  }

                 //   catch (e: JSONException)
                  //  {
                    //    e.printStackTrace()
                   // }
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Size here is"+ allMessage?.size ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }

        ).executeAsync()
```

for now what i did i implimented a Toast message inside my for loop which returning the 1st Object of json Array

```
               }
                            if (i==0) {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "" + insidata, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
```

but when i implimented this

```
          }
                            if (i==0) {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "" + mId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

i don't undERsTAND WHY IT IS  Still RETURNING NULL
plz help me get out of it
                                }

Comment: do you have 2 `mArrayList` variable in whole class??

Comment: Yeah I declared it globaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jArray != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
    listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
   } 
}
```

Comment: updated my question by applying ur suggested code still it's returning null

Comment: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[{"created_time":"2018-06-27T14:26:31+0000","id":"1742085185888234_1693593180737435"} from response it's very much clear my graph request returning values.